# Rails route stacked together

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to make the url look like this.

```
localhost:3000/teams/teamname/playername/
```

I've already made it so the teamname is displayed after teams, but I don't know how to show the players name after that.

- Edit -

I've got it to work but not exactly the way I want it to.

```
  get 'teams/:link/players' => 'players#index'
  get 'teams/:link/players/new' => 'players#new'
  get 'teams/:link/players/:link' => 'players#show'
  get 'teams/:link/players/:link/edit' => 'players#edit'
```

This displays localhost:3000/teams/teamname/players/playername/.
Is this the only possible way?

Comment: Let's discuss this on chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48530/ror

Answer (score 1):

As per the chat discussion with OP,

Association was incorrectly setup:

Changed

```
class Player < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_one :team 
end
```

To

```
class Player < ActiveRecord::Base 
  belongs_to :team 
end
```

Also, added foreign_key `team_id` in `players` table by generating a migration with:

```
rails g migration AddTeamIdToPlayers team:references
```

Then Run `rake db:migrate`

Finally, in `routes.rb`:

Change

```
get 'teams/:link/players/:link' => 'players#show' 
get 'teams/:link/players/:link/edit' => 'players#edit'
```

To

```
get 'teams/:teamname/:playername' => 'players#show', as: :show_player 
get 'teams/:teamname/:playername/edit' => 'players#edit', as: :edit_player
```

The new routes can be accessed as:
For example:

```
<%= link_to "Player", show_player(@team.name, @player.name)
```

where `@team` refers to an instance of `Team` and `@player` refers to an instance of `Player`.